# await and async blocking the UI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I wrote a little winforms application that search for files on the disk (what file is not that important for the sake of the question). the problem is the that it can be even 100,000 files or so. so this operation takes time.

What I want to achieve is to do the search operation as an async operation and not to block the UI thread so the form won't get stuck.

I can do this with the backgroundWorker but for some reason not with the async\await mechanism.

Here is my code:

```
private async void button_FindFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await SearchFilesUtil.SearchPnrFilesAsync(this.textBox_mainDirectory.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("After SearchPnrFilesAsync");
}

public async static Task SearchPnrFilesAsync(string mainDir)
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(mainDir, ".xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        var fileContenet = File.ReadAllText(file);
        var path = Path.Combine(@"C:\CopyFileHere", Path.GetFileName(file));
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            await sw.WriteAsync(fileContenet);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the UI thread get stuck and not displaying the `MessageBox` immediately?
what am I missing ?

Comment: Where is `mainDir` and how many files are in there?

Comment: mainDir is on c drive and there can be 200-300k of files in the directory tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact of marking `SearchPnrFilesAsync` with `async` keyword itself doesn't magically starts execution ot this method asynchronously in separate task.

In fact, all of the code in `SearchPnrFilesAsync` except `sw.WriteAsync` executes in UI thread thus blocking it.

If you need to execute your whole method in separate task, you can do it by wrapping like:

```
public async static Task SearchPnrFilesAsync(string mainDir)
{
   await Task.Run(() => your_code_here);
}
```

Comment: @dotctor Why not, if OP need this method to run completely in another task? Not only `ReadAllText` mentioned by you runs synchronously, but `Directory.EnumerateFiles` also.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I agree with you. Its just a example.

Comment: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

Comment: [Why you shouldn’t create asynchronous wrappers with Task.Run()](http://www.ben-morris.com/why-you-shouldnt-create-asynchronous-wrappers-with-task-run/)

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateFiles` does not have high overhead. The main reason for UI freezing is just `ReadAllText`.

Comment: @dotctor Thank you for the links, I've found these articles interesting. 
Yes, it looks like some guidelines violation to use `Task.Run` in a such manner because it will achieve only offloading and not scalability. So probably, in OP's situation it's better not to use async/await but deal with manually created Task. It is still important if he wants to achieve high UI responsibiliy since `Directory.EnumerateFiles` **can** be a bottleneck in the case of large amount of files in directory/child directories. In fact, if files amount is about some thousands - it will take few seconds on typical PC

Answer (score 4):

> Why does the UI thread get stuck?

Probably because you have some blocking work done on the UI thread, such as reading a file.

> Why is my MessageBox not displayed immediately?

Because that is not how `async` works. When you `await` a method, it asynchronously yields control to the caller until the operation is done. When the first `await` is hit, you start reading files from disk and copying them. `await` does not mean "execute this on a different thread and continue".

What you probably want to do is use an asynchronous reading mechanism instead of the blocking `File.ReadAllText`. You can do this using `StreamReader`:

```
public static async Task SearchPnrFilesAsync(string mainDir)
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(mainDir, ".xml",
                                                        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(@"C:\CopyFileHere", Path.GetFileName(file));
        using (var reader = File.OpenRead(file))
        using (var writer = File.OpenWrite(path))
        {
            await reader.CopyToAsync(writer);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: @dotctor You don't have to, it's one way of doing it. If the file is large, you don't want to consume it entirely into memory. Depends on what the OP needs.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov - thx for the idea but this code is still blocking the UI thread.

Comment: You can use the [Stream.CopyToAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.stream.copytoasync "Stream.CopyToAsync Method") method.

Comment: @Paulo Yes, perhaps that is even better.

Comment: It's shorter and easy to read, at least. And it doesn't allocate for the entire file contents, which is bad if big files are being read/written. This way, a 81920 byte buffer will be allocated for each file ([Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/08ee62b6d544c8fe.html)). Given that there can be 100000 files, there will be 100000 allocations of 81920. I would use one single local buffer to copy the contents. I'm assuming this is an academic issue, because in the real world, I would use [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.file.copy).

Comment: @Paulo Problem there is no asynchronous equivalent of `File.Copy`. But yes, I've thought about that as well as another optional answer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, and that's a flaw of the framework and/or OS. But, there's always `Task.Run`! :)

Comment: @Paulo Yup, But I hate giving example of using proper async methods and then deferring to `Task.Run` in the lack of an async counterpart. But still, could be of use.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the UI thread get stuck

I've tested the code you posted doesn't make UI blocked.
When `SearchPnrFilesAsync` running, I was able to resize the window and click the button as well.
Did you think it was blocked because it didn't show the "After SearchPnrFilesAsync" message? If Something I wrong, please let me know.

> not displaying the MessageBox immediately

The `await` keyword inside the `button_FindFiles_Click` function asynchronously waits for the `SearchFilesUtil.SearchPnrFilesAsync` function to finish.
That's why "After SearchPnrFilesAsync" message doesn't pop up as soon as the button is clicked.
If you want the `SearchFilesUtil.SearchPnrFilesAsync` function to be executed as soon as you click the button
and immediately you want to check the message, you can call the method without `await` keyword.

```
SearchFilesUtil.SearchPnrFilesAsync(this.textBox_mainDirectory.Text);
```

When you don't use `await` on a function that returns a `Task`, you'll get a "warning".
In this case, use `discards` feature and the warning will disappear. (With C# 7)

```
_ = SearchFilesUtil.SearchPnrFilesAsync(this.textBox_mainDirectory.Text);
```

If you want to know more about it, please check out this link (
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards)

Comment: thank you for your answer.....after 6 years :)